# Acoustic Echo Canceler (AEC) not cancelling echo

Tags: java, android, voip, aec

So I'm trying to develop an android VoIP application. I'm having trouble making the echo cancellation work and can still hear myself talk when on loudspeaker mode.

```
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, mSampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

echoCanceler = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(recorder.getAudioSessionId());
                echoCanceler.setEnabled(true);
```

Ive tried changing settings to `CHANNEL_IN_STEREO`. Changing playback settings to `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATON` but still no luck.

Im using a samsung S7 and Nexus 5 to test.

Answer (score 1):

Echo cancellation on android is not a simple task especially if you want to support multiple phones and multiple versions of Android. Start by some reading on the behavior and challenge of [echo cancellation](http://solicall.com/echo-cancellation-art-or-science-part-v/). Then, you can try an open source solution (e.g. Speex). If the open source does not work, then you should look for a professional echo cancellation. Simply google for echo cancellation software.